# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3

Tags: java, ojdbc

I am new in programming world. I tried to make a simple login however, I  getting this error:

> missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3

I've tried to find the answer but I still can't recognize the problem in my coding.

Here is my LoginServlet

```
package apl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import apl.LoginDao;


public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String i=request.getParameter("sid");  
        String n=request.getParameter("sname");
        String p=request.getParameter("sphone");  
        String u=request.getParameter("susername");  
        String w=request.getParameter("spassword");


        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if(session!=null)
        session.setAttribute("sid", i);

        if(LoginDao.validate(i,n,p,u,w)){  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");  
            rd.forward(request,response);  
        }  
        else{  
            out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password incorrect</p>");  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");  
            rd.include(request,response);  
        }  

        out.close();  
    }  
}
```

Here is my LoginDao

```
package apl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoginDao {

        public static boolean validate(String sid, String sname, String sphone, String susername, String spassword) {  

            boolean status = false;
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","apl","system");

                pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from SELLER where sid=?,sname=?,sphone=?,susername=? and spassword=?");

                pst.setString(1, sid);              
                pst.setString(2, sname);                
                pst.setString(3, sphone);
                pst.setString(4, susername);
                pst.setString(5, spassword);


                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                status = rs.next();            


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (pst != null) {
                    try {
                        pst.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return status;    
        }
    }
```

Here is my jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px">
            <legend> Login to App </legend>
            <table>
               <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sid" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sname" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="sphone" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="susername" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="spassword" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>apl.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please don't use Stack Snippets for material that is not CSS, HTML or JavaScript. Java cannot be run in a browser using a Snippet.

Comment: sorry and thanks for the comment. i'll improve it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL `where` clause, `and` operator is missing, so you need to add it as shown below:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from SELLER where sid=?
 and sname=? and sphone=? and susername=? and spassword=?")
```

Comment: i've tried to modify it but it's not working. do you have another suggestions?

Comment: still the same. "missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3"

Comment: I doubt, the latest code is not uploaded to the server? check the `.class` files when they are loaded to the server

Comment: Thanks ! The problem solved. what i did is clean the project and build it again. :)

Comment: great, I know that, latest class files not loaded to classpath